# how to await for vscode api window messages

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am trying to build a vs code extension with a lot of async features. However, I cannot make some of them work. For example:

```
let isSane = await vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`You are merging ${currentBranch} into development. Are you sure?`, ...['Continue'])

if (!isSane) { return }

let status = await utils.getWorkingTreeStatus()

if (!status) { return }

await cmd.execute(git.info.path, ['checkout', 'development']) 
let isMergable = await utils.getMergability(currentBranch)

const mergeStatus = await utils.handleMerge(currentBranch, isMergable, true)
```

This code does not wait for the user to do something with the first information message and just moves forward with the merge with the information box still hanging there.

What am I missing here and how do I fix this?

Comment: Why your code looks so different? https://github.com/vscode-restructuredtext/vscode-restructuredtext/blob/153.0.0/src/util/python.ts#L57

Comment: The only difference I see is the const-let and the spread operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax. What do you mean?